# filtering infrastructure for fluentnhibernate over 3 tiers application

Tags: c#, wcf, fluent-nhibernate, filtering

i have a 3 tier app that needs to be capable of doing data filtering according to user requests, i'm working with fluentnhibernate to manage the crud of my entities.

my question is how can i pass the filter from the client to the server (over wcf).

the filter classes of fn is not serializable.

any solution?

Comment: Removed WPF tag as question has no relationship to that technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: create a serializable object that contains the filter specification. For simple filters, an enumeration should do just fine. Then, in your WCF service, map from this filter specification to something that the lower layers of the application understand.

NHibernate (and other object-relational mappers) are tied to database retrieval. It doesn't really make sense for your client UI to be this closely coupled to your persistence system, and by attempting to use the NHibernate filter objects you'll be using them for something they're not designed for.

Some applications I've seen have multiple layers, each with their own data types: one for the UI, one for validation logic on the UI, one for data transfer between client and service, one for the business logic in the domain at the server, and one for persistence. It might seem extreme but this means that the objects can properly reflect the needs of each particular concern.

For example, you may need to compromise your data types to get your objects to serialize across a service boundary. Using different objects here from those used in the UI and business logic layers hides any ugliness.

Comment: don't you think its better to use the abstarvct restiction of nhibernate?

Comment: Chen - The problem I see with using the Restriction, or any class from NHibernate, is that by doing so you push the NHibernate namespace and reference up to you clients.  Many people prefer to keep NHibernate abstracted behind their service layer. In which case they have to create their own criteria object and then map that object to NHibernate Criteria.